# boost asio async_connect callback not called even when connection was established

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am running into this issue occasionally. 
We have an http client implemented with boost::asio and a deadline_timer to handle connection/request timeout.

1. `async_connect` is called. deadline_timer is started with a 120 sec timeout.
2. `deadline_timer` callback gets called after 120 sec and it explicitly closes the connection.
3. `async_connect_callback` is called with error_code `boost::system::errc::operation_canceled` and here I also see that the timer has expired.
4. TcpDump to capture network traffic shows that the tcp connection was established successfully and it is closed after 120 secs.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to investigate why the async_connect callback was not called to denote successful connection establishment?
2. Is it possible that io_service queue was overloaded? If so, what explains the async_connect_callback getting called as a result of the timeout?
   Also the program uses a threadpool of 40 threads, if it matters.

Comment: Without your code, it's going to be hard to say something really useful. I suggest you bring the code down to a minimum viable example that exposes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Without your code, it's going to be hard to say something really useful. I suggest you bring the code down to a minimum viable example that exposes the problem.

> 1. Is there a way to investigate why the async_connect callback was not called to denote successful connection establishment?

You may benefit from [Handler Tracking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/handler_tracking.html). When enabled you get a pretty complete picture of what operations are pending when and what completion handlers are (not) called.

Sample looks like:

```
@asio|1298160085.070638|0*1|signal_set@0x7fff50528f40.async_wait
@asio|1298160085.070888|0*2|socket@0x7fff50528f60.async_accept
@asio|1298160085.070913|0|resolver@0x7fff50528e28.cancel
@asio|1298160118.075438|>2|ec=asio.system:0
@asio|1298160118.075472|2*3|socket@0xb39048.async_receive
@asio|1298160118.075507|2*4|socket@0x7fff50528f60.async_accept
@asio|1298160118.075527|<2|
@asio|1298160118.075540|>3|ec=asio.system:0,bytes_transferred=122
@asio|1298160118.075731|3*5|socket@0xb39048.async_send
@asio|1298160118.075778|<3|
@asio|1298160118.075793|>5|ec=asio.system:0,bytes_transferred=156
@asio|1298160118.075831|5|socket@0xb39048.close
@asio|1298160118.075855|<5|
@asio|1298160122.827317|>1|ec=asio.system:0,signal_number=2
@asio|1298160122.827333|1|socket@0x7fff50528f60.close
@asio|1298160122.827359|<1|
@asio|1298160122.827370|>4|ec=asio.system:125
@asio|1298160122.827378|<4|
@asio|1298160122.827394|0|signal_set@0x7fff50528f40.cancel
```

Note that Asio comes with a perl script to generate graphviz graphs from this:

```
~/custom/boost/libs/asio/tools/handlerviz.pl /tmp/raw.log | dot -Tpng -o q.png
```

[image]

> 2. Is it possible that io_service queue was overloaded?

Only if you program it that way. The usual pattern is that all tasks posted to `io_service` should be non-blocking and short lived. If so, you should be able to multiplex serious IO load on just 1 thread no problem.

> If so, what explains the async_connect_callback getting called as a result of the timeout?

This is by design when the service object (in your case, the socket) gets closed (or even destructed). The docs say that all pending asynchronous operations are canceled in such a case, and the completion handlers will fire with ec=125 (`boost::asio::error::operation_abored`) exactly like you say.

> Also the program uses a threadpool of 40 threads, if it matters.

Erm. That's a lot. Why is this? Do you actually have 40 logical CPU cores? Are you using the service for more than just IO tasks? In the latter case I strongly suspect the problem is that you "abuse" the IO queue for long-running or (god forbid) blocking tasks, which means that IO tasks *can* be starved.

This might seem unlikely, but the likelihood increases in the presence of strands, and in particular if the strand participates in such a blocking operation. In that case, the whole pool logically acts as-if 1 single thread for every operation on the strand.